# Statistics on RPG.se Questions Closed and Reopened in 2016

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, site-statistics

Shog9 has put together a bunch of statistics on question closing and reopening in 2016 for all the sites on MSE: [2016: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289797/2016-a-year-in-closing). I've pulled in the data for just RPG.se here, for the community's edification and discussion, and to put it in a more digestible format.

\begin{array}{rrr}
\text{Questions…} \\
\text{Asked} & \text{Closed} & \text{%} \\ \hline
5127 & 1605 & 31.30
\end{array}

Breakdown per close type:

\begin{array}{l|rr|rr}
\text{Close Reason} & \text{Closed} & \text{% of Total}  & \text{Reopened} & \text{(%)} \\ \hline
\text{Duplicate} & 244 & 15.20 & 34 & (14.93) \\
\text{Off Topic} & 344 & 21.43 & 25 & (7.27) \\
\text{Unclear} & 356 & 22.18 & 166 & (46.63) \\
\text{Too Broad} & 345 & 21.50 & 84 & (24.35) \\
\text{Primarily Opinion-Based} & 316 & 19.69 & 63 & (19.94) \\
\end{array}

Note that there's one oddity in how the stats work: the questions closed in 2016 may have been asked in any year. That means that the asked:closed ratio is more a matter of site activities than whether the questions asked this year were closed or not. (See the line for Anime in the [original data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289797/2016-a-year-in-closing) for an example of how this, plus unusual activity — a massive cleanup last year, in their case — can give counter-intuitive numbers.)

Comment: As an interesting side note - our mod stats only have a quarter worth of lookback and not a year option, but mods closed 122 questions last quarter, so multiplying by 4 you can probably say mods only even participated in closing in about 25% of cases.  Good work community!